# How does Linux pick which modules to load?

Tags: drivers, upgrade, intel, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

```
uname -a
Linux guru 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1 [...] x86_64 [...]
```

When I reboot, I see the following in syslog:

```
Dec 29 06:30:22 guru kernel: [...] e1000e: Intel PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.1.4-k
```

However:

```
cd /lib/modules/3.8.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
strings e1000e.ko | grep -i version
version=2.5.4-NAPI
```

`modinfo e1000e` gives me the same version (`2.5.4-NAPI`)

On boot, I believed that the kernel walked through `/lib/modules/{version string}/kernel/drivers` and loaded what it needed ...

but clearly I'm mistaken

There exist two other versions of e1000e.ko on this boot drive:

```
/lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
/lib/modules/3.8.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
```

And both of these are version 2.1.4-k ... is the kernel somehow grabbing modules from these older locations?

Rule out:

```
grep -r e1000e /etc/*
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
```

in other words, no mention of this module in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist*` or `/etc/init/module-init-tools.conf`, etc.

I note that:
`/lib/modules/3.8.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko used to be version 2.1.4-k` ... but then I upgraded per http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-032514.html and rebooted ... which brought me to where I stand now

Is there a way to query a currently running module to ask from where on disk it was loaded?

--sk

Stuart Kendrick

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `modprobe` loads only same running kernel version modules, ie from:

```
/lib/modules/<kerne-version>/
```

`modinfo` shows the full path of the SUPPOSED module to be run by current kernel (not the one which currently running really). So you can't relay on it. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Example:

```
$ modinfo e1000e
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
version:        2.3.2-k
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     FAFC167239309C03F11F440
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
[...]
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ptp
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2A:DE:ED:EA:6C:BA:0B:95:A6:22:22:40:71:1F:49:C8:72:07:BB:F6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
parm:           copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:           TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:           IntMode:Interrupt Mode (array of int)
parm:           SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:           KumeranLockLoss:Enable Kumeran lock loss workaround (array of int)
parm:           WriteProtectNVM:Write-protect NVM [WARNING: disabling this can lead to corrupted NVM] (array of int)
parm:           CrcStripping:Enable CRC Stripping, disable if your BMC needs the CRC (array of int)
```

If it doesn't show it try: `modinfo -n e1000e` or `modinfo --filename e1000e`

```
/lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
```

It is possible to use `insmod` to load a specific module by full path. But this could be harmful and it could damage hardware. However, in most cases kernel will apply strict checks, raising some errors like (notice `3.13.0-37-generic` loaded successfull):

```
$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.11.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.11.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko: Invalid module format
$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko: Invalid module format
$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko: Invalid parameters
$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
$ sudo rmmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko: Invalid module format
```

I think `sysfs` shows the actual loaded module:

```
$ more /sys/module/e1000e/version 
2.3.2-k
$ more /sys/module/e1000e/srcversion 
FAFC167239309C03F11F440
```

I couldn't check it as `3.13.0-37-generic` & `3.13.0-38-generic` in my case have same versions.

**Note:**

Just to be complete, dynamically loaded kernel modules are handled by `dkms`, loaded from:

```
/var/lib/dkms/<driver-name>/<driver-last-version>/<kernel-version>/<kernel-arch>/module/
```